# How to activate or install the Gallery Widget?

Tags: widgets

I would like to activate the *Gallery Widget* which is presented [here](https://en.support.wordpress.com/widgets/gallery-widget/). It seems that it's part of the general Wordpress distribution but the widget is not listed under **Appearance** → **Widgets**. BTW, I don't see most of the widget present [here](https://en.support.wordpress.com/category/widgets-sidebars/). I only have the widgets described [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_SubPanel).

So, is there a way of installing that widget? Is it a plugin I need to install? Or is the selection of available widget dependent on the Theme?

BTW, I'm using Wordpress 4.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those plugins are only included for wordpress.com hosted websites specifically, and not included by default in a normal WordPress installation. Some of those plugins are available to download through the plugins section of you WordPress install, but I'm not sure if all of them are. For the gallery, try searching here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/widget-gallery there are hundreds of gallery plugins available.

Comment: You seem to be right. Most of the functionality seems to be included in the [Jetpack plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/), specifically they have a Gallery Widget: http://jetpack.me/support/extra-sidebar-widgets/gallery-widget/